# Private docker container registery not showing images but curl (API request) does

Tags: docker, docker-registry

We have a private docker registery in our work environment,The one who setup is no longer a part of our organization. Recently we created few new images and pushed those to our private registery, but after ssh to container regitery and using command `docker images` not showing latest images. All images are around week old. Similarly when we curl or sent get request from browser we can see the images there. What can be the possible cause. I am fairly new to this docker and private registery thing. These are the steps i am following.

**From my local machine**

1. docker tag f3d44b969827 192.x.x.x:5000/myappname:v1.0
2. docker push 192.x.x.x:5000/myappname:v1.0
3. ssh user@host
4. docker images  (latest image is not in list all previous once are displayed. which are not mine )

**From my local machine**

5. Open browser
6. http://192.x.x.x:5000/v2/_catalog (can see all repositories including the latest one which i have pushed.)
7. http://192.x.x.x:5000/v2/myappname/tags/list (can see all tags)

This is kind of mystery for me. Why it is behaving like this and how can i view these using `docker images`  after ssh into my private registery.

Comment: It doesn't work like this. The image is put to disk in some sort of data blobs. It doesn't just show up if you do image ls on the host. Finding it on disk requires mounting a volume to the registry container, otherwise it's only inside the registry container (if you use container).

Comment: You can also configure other types of storage https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/#storage

Comment: thanks i did a docker pull 192.x.x.x:5000/myappname:v1.0 on registery and it appeared. Don`t know if this is the correct way

Comment: It's not useful to do that. You don't need the image extracted on the host. The registry can serve it to you from the configured storage. Having the image available to run on the host is independent of that.

Comment: Much appreciated thanks.